# Putting values into an array and using array_sum

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, array-sum

ok im a little stuck, i know its a simple thing im missing here so hoping fresh eyes will help

I have values in a column stored as 2:7:99 etc each value is seperated by :

Now I can seperate all the values out and query another table to get the price which corresponds to that value.

The issue i'm having is doing a SUM of all the price values
See code below
I think the easiest way would be to add all the price values into an array and then do array_sum() but for some reason i just cant get it working

** Please DO NOT Mention SQL Injection .. Its on a LOCAL machine with NO outside access and only myself will be using this

```
    <?php
include('config.php');
// Function for calculation Rough Invoice Total
function basicTotal() {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","TABLE");
    $wtbdq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE wsjid = '18'");
    $wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq);
    do {
    $wtbd = explode(":",$wtbdr['worktobedone']);
    foreach($wtbd as $item) 
        {
            $priceq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-items` WHERE wsiid = '$item'");
            $pricer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceq);

            $price = array($pricer['incvat']);

            echo $item.' - '. $pricer['incvat'].'<br>';

        }

    } while($wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq));

    $total = array_sum($price);
    echo $total;
}
basicTotal();
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `$total = 0; foreach(...) {... $total += $pricer['incvat']; ...}`?

Comment: Why not use SELECT *, SUM(incvat) AS total FROM `workshop-items` WHERE wsiid = '$item' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are all the time overwriting you final price:

```php
$price = array($pricer['incvat']);
```

Replace that with:

```php
$price[] = $pricer['incvat'];
```

Comment: Any idea why its adding up the values of all the records  and not just the current row

Comment: It should be adding only the ones that comes from `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE wsjid = '18'`. Debug that this query is not returning all IDs you are then using to get the prices. But you can explain a little more about what is exactly happening now. I think you should open a new question.

Comment: Hi ive raised a new question showng all code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028136/array-sum-counting-all-records-in-result-query-not-each-row-individually

Answer (score 4):

```
just replace  $price = $pricer['incvat']; 

with this in your code

$price[] = $pricer['incvat'];
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your current approach is you are overwriting the `$price` variable. You need to push the value in the `$price` array like `$price[] = $pricer['incvat']`. You need to do this

```
    <?php
include('config.php');
// Function for calculation Rough Invoice Total
function basicTotal() {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USER","PASS","TABLE");
    $wtbdq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE wsjid = '18'");
    $wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq);
    do {
    $wtbd = explode(":",$wtbdr['worktobedone']);
    foreach($wtbd as $item) 
        {
            $priceq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-items` WHERE wsiid = '$item'");
            $pricer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceq);

            $price[] = $pricer['incvat'];

            echo $item.' - '. $pricer['incvat'].'<br>';

        }

    } while($wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq));

    $total = array_sum($price);
    echo $total;
}
basicTotal();
?>
```